# Is it possible to switch a view without a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I got only so far to be able to switch a view by pressing a button or with a timer. But I don't get it to switch a view by events like didReceiveLocalNotification. Is it impossible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, that's possible** , Because usually we specify the `method` with `notification` in which we wish to receive it.

Put the same code from your `UIButton` `action:` to `notification` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you have to do is doing the switch inside the method didReceiveLocalNotification.
You will need to send a message to the view controller you want to perform the switch.